# how Kotlin interpret {} or () by a run example

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main (){
    run(::topLevel)
    run{::topLevel}
    run{topLevel()}
    run(topLevel())
    }
fun topLevel() = println("print something")
```

1,2 run will execute the fun
3- will not execute
4- is an error

By this example i find that () and {} have different meaning. 
Would appreciate a lot if some one will explain how Kotlin interpret this 4 cases.

Comment: `{}` is a lambda of signature `() -> Unit` while `()` is a function invoking operator. The first and third will compile, not the second one.

Comment: indeed @AnimeshSahu

Answer (score 3):

If you see the declaration of the `run` function,

```kotlin
public inline fun <R> run(block: () -> R): R {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    return block()
}
```

It takes a block (a lambda) of signature `() -> R`. And the curly parenthesis (`{}`) create a lambda of that signature.

For instance `{}` has signature `() -> Unit`, `{ 4 }` has signature `() -> Int`. These are compatible with the run function.

What essentially happens when you call run is:

```kotlin
run { topLevel() }

// is equivalent to
run() { topLevel() }

// is equivalent to
run({ topLevel })
```

Hope-fully you understood the lambdas, which are created by curly braces `{}` and can be put outside the invokation of the function.

Now if you talk about `::` operator, it returns a reference of the function which is itself a lambda signature.

For example, `::topLevel` will return `() -> Unit` as it takes no argument and returns nothing (which is Unit).

---

Second and fourth will not work because.

In second: `run{::topLevel}` this passes passes `() -> () -> Unit` to the run. i.e. it passes a function which returns a reference to function `topLevel`. And hence to make it work, you have to write:

```kotlin
run{::topLevel}()
```

What it does is return the `::topLevel` on which we invoke using `()` that calls `topLevel`.

The fourth one won't compile because you are passing Unit (return type) of the `topLevel` function returned by calling it there like `topLevel()`

Answer (score 1):

in kotlin when you use `{}` and write something in it it means you are passing a block to the `trailing lambda`.

when you use `()` means you are passing a value, so:

1. `run(someFunction())` -> this means you are passing the **return** value of `someFunction()` as a parameter to `run()` which will fail simply because `run` does not take a value as parameter, however it takes a lambda as a parameter.
2. `run{someFunction}` -> this means you are passing a `lambda` or a `block` to be called inside `run` body. This will work cuz it simply satisfies `run` function signature.

```
public inline fun <R> run(block: () -> R): R
```